# How can so many memory cells fit on MicroSd card?

Tags: microsd

I just wondered, when I saw my new MicroSd memory card , how the hell can 32GB fit in that space?

Simple math:

it's around \$\frac{1}{2}cm^2\$ (my estimate, most of it is controllers anyway)
and it contains 32GB cells. So \$\frac{5*10^{-5}}{2^{(5+30)}} = 1.45*10^{-15} m^2\$ space for one cell. Since atoms are in area about \$10^{-12} m^2\$ , how come the memory cells are smaller than atoms?

Here is an image of what a microSD card looks like:

[image: MircoSD Card]

Comment: Many high capacity microSD cards are created from several stacked flash memories.

Comment: So it's in layers? interesting, I wonder If there is any limit to the amount of data to be stored on a microSd card.

Comment: more layers, more cost. Also, microSDHC is limited to 2 terabytes I believe, in terms of physical addressing.

Comment: SD is up to 2GB. SDHC is used for 2GB-64GB. SDXC is used from 64GB to , potentially, 2TB. But I wouldn't be surprised if there would be a faster communication protocol implemented before 2TB would comes around.

Comment: Questions support [math latex](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question) for equations in questions.

Comment: Is there a way or a tool to fix any physical errors in such cards, so that when we store important data we can retrieve from that.

Comment: Your figure for the size of an atom is completely wrong - you squared the units, but it looks like you forgot to square the numeric part of the linear dimension.  Though even doing that would seem to be a little wrong.  Where did you get your information?

Comment: Samsung has just announced the development of a [96-layer QLC flash chip](https://www.custompcreview.com/news/samsung-announces-96-layer-qlc-v-nand-ngsff-sz985-z-nand-ssd-fms-2017/). Each die has 96 stacked layers of flash cells (and there maybe a couple of stacked *dies* in one package), each one is capable of QLC. QLC means 4 bits per cell (each cell stores 1 of 16 different analog values rather than just a 1 or 0, longevity takes a major hit, but capacity goes way up). Tricks like that are a major part of how that much data gets crammed into such a small space.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flash memory is currently made in a \$19nm = 1.9 * 10^{-8}\$ m process. Since a cell is basically just one transistor, this leads to a minimum of \$3.6 * 10^{-16} m^2\$per cell.

In silicon, the inter-atomic distance is about \$2.35 *10^{-10}m\$. Making the area that an atom occupies about \$5 * 10^{-20} m^2\$.

Now you have to see that each cell is a three-dimensional object, leading to about \$10^6\$ atoms per cell.

Fits easily...

Mind you, the above numbers are estimates, ignoring material mix etc.

Now lets look at the area size of a 64 Gbit chip. Thats about \$7 * 10^{10}\$ cells. If it were square-ish, it would have about \$2.5 * 10^5\$ cells per row. Whoops, thats \$2 * 2.5 * 10^{-8} * 10^5 = 5 * 10^{-3} m = 5mm\$ square at least.

For a 32GB card, we'd need 4 of those. So yes, they probably are stacked.

With the expected higher integration, maybe down to a 10nm process, and threedimensional stacking of transistors within the chip, it looks like the volumetric size will be reduced by about a factor of ten within a year or two.

Comment: There are also multilevel cells which store more than one bit.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the latest (128GB) cards have as many as 17 thinned chips stacked up with in some cases 11nm chip features, 3 bits per cell and other "Fun Stuff" (tm).
They don't seem to be that more sensitive to X-rays than a 2GB but they are notably "hotter" than low density cards and can draw far more current when writing data.